# Get api requests to be processed sequentially

Tags: rest, apache-kafka

I am sending messages with two different users in the same method in the api How can I ensure that the messages of the second user are not read before the reading of the messages of the first user ends?

[image]

[image]

This is how it works right now 1 message from the first request 2. he reads a message from the request. First, read the messages in the first request, and then 2. how can I make it optional?

[image]

Comment: It'd be great if you could show your actual Kafka client code behind the rest api, or better describe your design. Otherwise, this doesn't seem like a Kafka question. Also, if you want more strict ordering, don't use async methods

Answer (score 1):

Ordering in Kafka is achieved by partition key. Every topic is internally divided into partitions and producer can optionally control the message-key while events are published to a topic.

If no key specified, it gets assigned to a random partition. But if we want to maintain an order to events, then make a unique key. Ex: customer Id can OR session key will be a good option for this. This will make sure that events published are being appended back to back offset in a partition.
[image]
Your requirement can be achieved by assigning a key as mentioned above but if it was the other way around, like second one to be consumed first followed by first message, I think it can never be achieved by Kafka alone.

Looking at your input, you are using a webservice to publish the events. Check if the service has got an option to mention the key for message. If its there, then use the same key for two events and it will be sorted. Otherwise you may need to enhance this service to accept keys as well, not just value.

A little more advanced one for batch processing : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-480%3A+Sticky+Partitioner

Comment: I have a producer similar to the one here how can I add a partition key https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet

Comment: ProduceAsync(string topic, Message<TKey, TValue> message); my producer method is such that I don't know where i can send the key here

Comment: Am not a dotnet dev, but of course you will be initiating a variable of type Message<TKey, TValue> message in your code. Here TKey forms the key while TValue forms the message body.

Comment: I'm not sure if the c# client has a sticky partitioner class